# What is difference between the operators ?? and ??= in C# 8.0

Tags: c#-8.0

What is between the operators ?? and ??= in C# 8.0? Following the msdn documentation:

> operator ?? **returns** the value of its left-hand operand if it isn't
>   null; otherwise, it evaluates the right-hand operand and returns its
>   result.
>
> Operator ??= **assigns** the value of its right-hand operand to its
>   left-hand operand only if the left-hand operand evaluates to null.

But results for both examples are the same

```
int? a = null;
int b = a ??= -1;
Console.WriteLine(b);  // output: -1

int? a = null;
int b = a ?? -1;
Console.WriteLine(b);  // output: -1
```

Comment: The first code block assigns `-1` to `a`. The second does not. Try printing the values of `a` afterwards to see the difference.

Comment: The second snippet *modifies `a`* as well.

Answer (score 3):

The first example `int b = a ??= -1;` is actually assigning `-1` to the variable `a`, then assigning the value of `a` to `b`. The `??=` operator is sort of like `+=`, `-=`, etc, so you can use it inline, such as:

```c#
int? a = null;
a ??= -1;    // a == -1

int? b = 123;
b ??= -1;    // b == 123
```

In the first example, you would really only need the `??=` if you want both `a` and `b` to take the value `-1` when `a` is `null`.

Your second example `int b = a ?? -1;` just assigns `a` to `b` if `a` is not null, otherwise `b` becomes `-1`.